# no suitable method found to override webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api

Greetings i have create an `Attribute` for a cleaner code, it simply checks out if `ModelState` is Valid, but it keeps giving me this error: no suitable method found to override on `OnActionExecuting`. by the way, i've used it on an `ActionResult` in my `Controller`.

here is my code:

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
   HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }

    }
}
```

here is my Controller:

```
    Repository<User> userRepository = new Repository<User>();

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Register"), AllowAnonymous, ValidateModelState]
    public ActionResult Create(UserRegister useReg)
    {
        userRepository.Insert(UserFactory.UserRegisterFactory(useReg));
        userRepository.save();
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using ActionFilterAttribute from namespace System.Web.Mvc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). Instead you should be using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx.

Comment: Oh You are right! Thank you! It worked like a Charm!